# How to set maximum downloads or sockets or whatever, in Apache and or PHP?

Tags: php, apache, download

I made a PHP script, running from my localhost, that streams files from a remote server and serves them. I do this so I can rename the files prior to the browser shows the dialog to save them, through `header( "filename:..." )`

Anyway, although the remote server allows many simultaneous file downloads at good rates, when they stream through my local apache/php I can't get more than 6 at the same time.

When I try to download the 7th, the save as dialog appears as soon as the sixth download has finished.

I'm almost sure this is some limit imposed by php.ini or apache's httpd.ini, but don't have a clue about which one is it. do you?

Comment: It's your browser limiting the connections...  It has nothing to do with Apache or PHP...  http://www.onetipaday.com/2007/07/31/how-to-increase-the-number-of-firefox-simultaneous-downloads/

Comment: I always thought that was a client issue. So you have identical code on 2 servers.  One local, one remote.  And you can only get 6 at a time off the local server, but on the remote server its unlimited?  Try putting the remote and local php.ini or httpd.conf files into a code comparison program and see what is different.

Comment: This is something that's more appropriate for ServerFault

Comment: @profitphp: I don't actually own the remote server. So can't access conf files. My local code is streaming the remote files. I can get the remote files directly, with no limit, but when I stream them through my local server, I get the 6 limit.

Comment: @ircmaxell: in my post I specify that I can download files from the remote server with no limit whatsoever, I was able to download more than 50 files from the same server at once.

Comment: @ircmaxell: Oh but then, following your link... network.http.max-persistent-connections-per-server is exactly 6. But it's working only on my local host. Thanks!!

Comment: @Petruza: I had a feeling ;-)

Comment: @ircmaxell: great :)  Now I've set firefox's limit to 99, but in practice it doesn't get greater than 16. Would that be a hard limit from FF? because I've downloaded far more than 16 files at once from a single host.

Comment: @Petruza: I have no idea.  Without looking at configurations, etc I can't really tell from here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's your browser limiting the connections... It has nothing to do with Apache or PHP... http://onetipaday.com/2007/07/31/… – @ircmaxell